# Android function to get simple response from php script

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

```
 public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String s;
        while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(s+"\n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I have this function to collect the response that is displayed in a simple php Script

```
<?php echo "sample"; ?>
```

but it seems to be always getting a null or empty value..cant figure out which part of the code is giving me problems... assuming the requestURL is working fine because i already tested it in web browser.....

Comment: How do you eat an elephant? One byte at a time. Test your php code indepently using your browser or postman. Test your android code by fetching static content of the expected values. Then only should you attempt to combine the two

Comment: @e4c5 tested my php script in my web browser and it was working fine, but for the method that i have to collect for data, it cant even get a simple line from a php script. i tested it with a script that only contains a simple echo <?php
echo "Sample";
?>

Comment: Then your PHP code need not have been posted here and this need not have been tagged as PHP, mysql, JSON. Work on your java code by connecting it to a static resource

Comment: thank you, ill try to research for solution first since i've narrowed down the issue... will be deleting the post later since its no longer related to the tags :D

Answer (score 0):

have you add INTERNET permission in your android manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`